# New theatre script with colours

Tags: color

I created this code by looking at other posts. I'd need to know how to get the black text back after the red parenthesis (\did command). Thank you a lot!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[noheadfoot, margin=2cm, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{nimbusmono}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}

\newlength{\postspeciskip}
\postspeciskip = 1.5\baselineskip

\newcommand\sce[1]{\color{black}\fontsize{20pt}\selectfont\newpage\raggedright{#1}\vskip 8mm\color{black}}

\newcommand\character[1]{\par\everypar{\hangindent=0.253\linewidth\hangafter=1}\parskip=0.8\baselineskip plus 1pt\fontsize{13pt}\selectfont\makebox[0.253\linewidth][r]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}\hskip0.1\linewidth }}

\newcommand\did[1]{\fontsize{13pt}\selectfont\color{blue}\raggedright\textit{#1}\vskip 8mm\color{black}\fontsize{13pt}\selectfont}%

\newcommand\g[1]{\color{red}\textsl{#1}}

\setlength\parindent {0pt}%

\interlinepenalty = 1000\parskip0pt plus \baselineskip

\begin{document}

% personaçs
\def\Marchese{\character{Marchês}}
\def\Conte{\character{Cont}}
\def\Fabrizio{\character{Fabrîç}}

%\scene

\sce{Sene 1 : Prove di scriture}

\did{Sala di locanda. Entra il Marchese di Forlipopoli ed il Conte d’Albafiorita}

\Marchese
Fra voi e me vi è qualche differenza.

\Conte
Sulla locanda tanto vale il vostro denaro, quanto vale il mio.

\Conte
Per qual ragione? \g{(un po' arrabbiato)}

\Marchese
\g{(arrabbiatissimo)} Io sono il Marchese di Forlipopoli.

\Conte Ed io sono il Conte d’Albafiorita.

\Marchese Sì, Conte! Contea comprata.

\Conte
Io ho comprata la contea, quando voi avete venduto il marchesato.

\Marchese
Oh basta: son chi sono, e mi si deve portar rispetto.

\Conte
Chi ve lo perde il rispetto? Voi siete quello, che con troppa libertà parlando...

\Conte
Oh, questa è bella! Voi mi vorreste impedire ch’io amassi Mirandolina? Perché credete ch’io sia in Firenze? Perché credete ch’io sia in questa locanda?

\Marchese
Uh bene. Voi non farete niente.


\end{document}
```

Comment: the posted code generates multiple errors you need to fix before looking at any colours in the output. After _any_ error the pdf output is not intended to be usable, just a possible debugging aid.  `\fontsize` takes two arguments, a font size and a baseline so `\fontsize{20pt}\selectfont` should be `\fontsize{20pt}{22pt}\selectfont` or more simply  `\huge`

Comment: `\raggedright` doesn't take an argument so `\raggedright{#1}` would make the rest of the document ragged.   for your actual question `\textcolor{red}{abc}`  just makes abc red, reverting to the original colour afterwards

Answer (score 1):

It was a bit hard to guess the intended layout but perhaps something like this, which at least gives no errors.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[noheadfoot, margin=2cm, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{nimbusmono}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}

\newlength{\postspeciskip}
\postspeciskip = 1.5\baselineskip

\newcommand\sce[1]{\newpage{\color{black}\LARGE\raggedright #1\par}}

\newcommand\character[1]{%
% these declarations all apply for the rest of the document not just this character
\par\everypar{\hangindent=0.253\linewidth\hangafter=1}%
\parskip=0.8\baselineskip plus 1pt
\large\MakeTextUppercase{#1}\hspace{\linewidth}}

\newcommand\did[1]{{\large\raggedright\textcolor{blue}{\textit{#1}}\par}}

\newcommand\g[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textsl{#1}}}

\setlength\parindent {0pt}%

\interlinepenalty = 1000\parskip0pt plus \baselineskip

\begin{document}
\raggedright

% personaçs
\def\Marchese{\character{Marchês}}
\def\Conte{\character{Cont}}
\def\Fabrizio{\character{Fabrîç}}

%\scene

\sce{Sene 1 : Prove di scriture}

\did{Sala di locanda. Entra il Marchese di Forlipopoli ed il Conte d’Albafiorita}

\Marchese
Fra voi e me vi è qualche differenza.

\Conte
Sulla locanda tanto vale il vostro denaro, quanto vale il mio.

\Conte
Per qual ragione? \g{(un po' arrabbiato)}

\Marchese
\g{(arrabbiatissimo)} Io sono il Marchese di Forlipopoli.

\Conte Ed io sono il Conte d’Albafiorita.

\Marchese Sì, Conte! Contea comprata.

\Conte
Io ho comprata la contea, quando voi avete venduto il marchesato.

\Marchese
Oh basta: son chi sono, e mi si deve portar rispetto.

\Conte
Chi ve lo perde il rispetto? Voi siete quello, che con troppa libertà parlando...

\Conte
Oh, questa è bella! Voi mi vorreste impedire ch’io amassi Mirandolina? Perché credete ch’io sia in Firenze? Perché credete ch’io sia in questa locanda?

\Marchese
Uh bene. Voi non farete niente.


\end{document}
```